# Spark program takes a really long time to complete execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark is supposed to finish data processing at lightening speed. But I guess I'm not using the right functionalities for my program to make Spark work that way.

This is how my program looks like:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyparsing import re
import time

start_time = time.time()
sc = SparkContext("local","test")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def func1(lines):
    for line in lines:
        qtype = re.search("qtype=(\S+)",line)
        try:
            url = re.search(" url=(\S+)",line)
            url=url.group(1)
        except:
            url="null"

        time = re.search("(^\S+)",line)
        .... #extracting field names
        row = Row(time = time.group(1),ttms = ttms.group(1),chi = chi.group(1),pssc = pssc.group(1),cqhm = cqhm.group(1),rtype = rtype.group(1),rdetails = rdetails.group(1),rurl = rurl.group(1),qtype = qtype.group(1),phn = phn.group(1),fqdn = fqdn,url = url)

    return row

file = sc.textFile("C:\\Logs\\filename.log").cache()
result = file.map(lambda x: x.split("\n"))
lines = result.map(func1).collect()
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lines)
df.registerTempTable("df")
df.show()

for line in df :
    query1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype,rtype,COUNT(qtype,rtype) from df GROUP BY qtype,rtype").collect()
    query2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype, COUNT(qtype) from df GROUP BY qtype").collect()
    query3 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df GROUP BY rtype").collect()
    query4 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df WHERE qtype = \"HTTP\" GROUP BY rtype").collect()

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query1)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query2)
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query3)
df4 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(query4)
df1.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv1.csv")
df2.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv2.csv")
df3.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv3.csv")
df4.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv4.csv")
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

This program takes almost 200 seconds to execute which is a very long time. I can't figure out the reason. (My log file contains around 34k log lines). I tried using spark's `filter` for regex expressions but I get the error that `rdd is not iterable`. So I need to know in what way can I optimize my program to make it run faster.
Also, I get the warning that `stage x contains task of very large size`. Tried broadcasting `lines` but gave an error.

Comment: Is this a single box or multi-node cluster that you're running against?  Could you clarify where in the code represents the query time?  Some quick observations that may help: 1) for `lines` do you need to run a collect?  2) for the `for line in df` did you want to create a DataFrame for each line in your uber-dataframe?

Comment: Can you try to explain please that is it your are trying to do ? It's not very clear for me. Also what's the size of the data ? How many entries in there in DF ?

Comment: @DennyLee : This is a single box that I'm using. I've just used python's `time` function to assess how long the entire program takes to execute.
1) I need to use collect for `lines` so that it gets converted to a list and can create df from that.
2) I'm not creating a df for each line, I'm just querying each line from the uber- df.

Comment: @eliasah : My program just reads log lines and extracts data matching the regex. After extraction, it queries each line in the DF and the result is copied to a csv. My data has 34k log lines which are in key-value pair format. So the DF contains the same data except that the key-values are in columns after extraction. DF has 34k rows.

Comment: @kaks - why do you try to implement your program in spark, instead of python? what do you benefit from pyspark here?

Comment: @Yaron : This is just the log processing. I will be doing a lot more later like creating partitions etc based on time. But this itself takes a long time to execute. I thought using spark functionalities will work faster than just python. I want to know whether I'm doing it the right way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

some reasons why this spark code will run slower vs. pure python code:

1) using one machine

```
sc = SparkContext("local","test")
```

python-spark might perform better than pure python when running on a cluster.
in "local" mode, spark has no advantage on pure python.

2) using "cache" when it isn't used

```
file = sc.textFile("C:\\Logs\\filename.log").cache()
```

.cache() should be used only when the same object is called more than once.
"file" is called only once - i.e. no need for cache

3) using "collect()"

```
lines = result.map(func1).collect()

for line in df :
    query1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype,rtype,COUNT(qtype,rtype) from df GROUP BY qtype,rtype").collect()
    query2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype, COUNT(qtype) from df GROUP BY qtype").collect()
    query3 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df GROUP BY rtype").collect()
    query4 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df WHERE qtype = \"HTTP\" GROUP BY rtype").collect()
```

A general rule - avoid using "collect()" unless it is really really needed.

4) using "toPandas()"

```
df1.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv1.csv")
df2.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv2.csv")
df3.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv3.csv")
df4.toPandas().to_csv("C:\\Sample logs\\sqlcsv4.csv")
```

"toPandas()" implementation start with execution of "collect()" (see #3)

**Since spark 2.0, you can write dataframe to CSV directly:**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

```
>>> df.write.csv(os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'data'))
```

5) I'm not sure that I understand the below code:

```
for line in df :
    query1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype,rtype,COUNT(qtype,rtype) from df GROUP BY qtype,rtype").collect()
    query2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT qtype, COUNT(qtype) from df GROUP BY qtype").collect()
    query3 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df GROUP BY rtype").collect()
    query4 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rtype, COUNT(rtype) from df WHERE qtype = \"HTTP\" GROUP BY rtype").collect()
```

what do you try to achieve in "for line in df:" ?

If the dataframe holds 100,000 rows, do you plan to execute this "for-loop" 100,000 times?

It seems like the variables query1, query2, query3, query4 will hold only the result of the last execution of the for-loop (as their value seems to be override every time you read a new "line" from "df") - is it by purpose?

6) You can create Dataframe directly from RDD

e.g. using

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

**createDataFrame(**data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None, verifySchema=True)
**Creates a DataFrame from an RDD,** a list or a pandas.DataFrame.

or

```
RDD.toDF()
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

toDF(*cols)

Returns a new class:DataFrame that with new specified column names
Parameters: cols – list of new column names (string)

```
>>> df.toDF('f1', 'f2').collect()
[Row(f1=2, f2=u'Alice'), Row(f1=5, f2=u'Bob')]
```

Comment: 2) and 5) worked tremendously. Thanks! I removed the for loop like you said in 5). 
The reason I use `collect` is cause the RDD will be converted to a list. Only then can I create a df out of it. Otherwise it would throw an error. Is there another way?
I thought converting to a csv is easier if using pandas.
For now I'm using only the local machine. I would start using cluster later.

Comment: @kaks - I've updated my answer, regarding df.write.csv() function.

Comment: @kaks - added a section about creating Dataframe directly from RDD